# Using address-of operator to match pointer parameter type?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have some code like this:

```
X& x = getXByRef();

myFunc(&x);
```

to call:

```
void myFunc(X*& x){
    // ...
}
```

where `getXByRef()`:

```
X& getX(){
    return _x;
}
```

which I thought I could do because I used the address-of operator, to match the pointer type. However it generates compiler warnings saying the stack variable type does not match the parameter type.

What is my misunderstanding here?

Comment: Paste that warning, literally, in its full form. Also, if you have control over `myFunc`, that signature looks scary. Is `_x` a global variable? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have function, that receives reference to pointer, but you are creating temporary pointer in `&x`. Actually it shouldn't be warning, but error (and is in gcc/clang, but not in MSVC).
Solution is simple:

```
X* ptr = &x;
myFunc(ptr);
```

But do you need pointer here actually?

Comment: I dont need pointer here, but the function myFunc() is also used where I do have to pass a pointer.

Comment: The function is used in some code which has about 3-4 nested levels of functions, where I currently pass a const X&, must I really change all these argument types to use X* ?

Comment: @user997112 it really depends on what function actually does.

Answer (score 1):

`myFunc` expects a (non-const) reference to a pointer to `X` as argument.

You're passing `&x`, which is a pointer to `X`. But it is a temporary, which cannot be passed by reference.

Either have `myFunc` accept a `X*` (pointer to `X`) or a `X* const &` (const reference to pointer to `X`). Or store `&x` in a variable before passing it as argument to the function.